# Detect how many apps are in running mode on device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an app where I have to detect whether there any app which is already running on device. I want the list of all running apps. I made R&D on this topic but I found nothing. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No public APIs for this, but you may find [this](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS-6-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/SBAppSwitcherModel.h) useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in a non-jailbreak app you can not do this.

However for a jailbroken app you can do : [Return a list of running background apps/processes in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906180/return-a-list-of-running-background-apps-processes-in-ios)

Also: [Detect which app is currently running on iOS using sysctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319817/detect-which-app-is-currently-running-on-ios-using-sysctl)

EDIT:

As  [this app in iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sys-activity-manager-for-memory/) does the same as you need, so you can go with above.

Comment: I think it is possible to do it with in a non-jailbreak, this app did it https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sys-activity-manager-for-memory/id447374159?mt=8, but I have no idea about how they accomplish this

Comment: I have found this: http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H, I can't test it right now, maybe you can take a look

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Do you know how to detect if a process is in background or foreground mode?

Comment: @JamesLaurenstin: you can check if a process is running but I am not sure you can check if it is in bg or fg.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I already know how to list the running processes. I'm just trying to figure out if they're in bg or fg? Not sure how to get that info yet.